# react native - screen doesnt show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so i want retrieve data from the .json and it doesnt showing up in my screen, i already console log the error but it shows up null. and i already doing console log the item

[restaurant context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJcN.png)
[image]

[restaurant screeen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwDP4.png)
[image]

[console log and screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bbsi.png)
[image]

[consolelogItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckcQ7.png)
[image]

Comment: if its a json file you can import it manually

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.